# PHP - Cannot pass Input to $_POST (retruns no value)

Tags: php, post

post.php (send post)

```html
    <form action="/profile/update.php">
    <textarea class="text-secondary locked092404292490" id="website_link" name="website_link" placeholder="ex: http://example.com"></textarea>
    <textarea class="text-secondary locked092404292490" id="github_link" name="github_link" placeholder="ex: Github Username"></textarea>
    <textarea class="text-secondary locked092404292490" id="twitter_link" name="twitter_link" placeholder="ex: Twitter Username"></textarea>
    <textarea class="text-secondary locked092404292490" id="instagram_link" name="instagram_link" placeholder="ex: Instagram Username"></textarea>
    <textarea class="text-secondary locked092404292490" id="facebook_link" name="facebook_link" placeholder="ex: Facebook Username"></textarea>
    <textarea id="profile_desc" class="col-sm-9 text-secondary" name="profile_desc"></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="username_who" value="<?= $page_user ?>" id="username_who">
    <button type="submit">ww</button>
    </form>
<!-- $page_user is defined as "bacon" -->
```

update.php (submitting)

```php
$post_username_Who = $_POST['username_who'];
echo 'Username'.$row['username'];
echo '<br> page_user'.$post_username_Who.'<br>';
```

`echo` returns nothing, even though I checked the server header, `username_who` was posted fine, but why won't it Post?

Comment: add `method="POST"` to your `<form>` element, otherwise it defaults to a get request

Comment: Where did you define `$row`? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: $row was already defined, Just the Post was the issue (completely forgot)

The main issue was with my post script (not all shown), i forgot an input feild (the hidden one) so kinda 1 shot killed 3 birds and a snake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it in 2 ways

1. Specify `method` into your form. This is the good practice. Like this
   `<form action="/profile/update.php" method="POST">`
   Because, if you don't specify `method` it will send data as get.

**or**

2. Get the data using `$_GET`